# What tool can I use to make multiple HTTP request?

Tags: http, httprequest

I've put in some code in my app to limit the number of page request being accepted from an IP.

I need to test it but I'm at a lost on what tool can be use for this purpose.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: coldfusion at the moment but it doesn't really matter as I just need to see the HTTP response. thanks

Comment: please checkout this https://www.hurl.it/

Comment: @mrjayviper Oh right sorry didn't understand your question at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Checkout links below,

[HURL.it](https://www.hurl.it/)

> Hurl.it makes HTTP requests.

[Requestbin](http://requestb.in/)

> RequestBin gives you a URL that will collect requests made to it and
>   let you inspect them in a human-friendly way.